# Can you suggest cheapest way to perform the journey in Italy?

Tags: trains, india, italy, trenitalia

3rd June evening: starting Toulon(France) reaching Milan (Italy)
4th June evening : starting Milan reaching Venice MAstre
6th June erly morning : starting Venice MAstre to Florance
6th evening : Florance to Rome termine

Comment: What train pass are you talking about?

Comment: italiapass or else i would request your views. Actually I will be at Tulon on 3rd June. and want to visit Italy after that

Comment: From my understanding [`Itaiarail's Italiapass is not a rail pass. It is a discount card which mainly offers money off other things than trains.`](https://www.tripadvisor.co.nz/ShowTopic-g187791-i22-k8595752-Trenitalia_vs_Italiarail_with_Italiapass-Rome_Lazio.html) I suggest you do some research first and then edit the question so that we can better understand what you are asking. :)

Comment: Best? What is best? Cheapest? Fastest? Most comfortable?

Comment: just edited the question to make it more clear